# Understanding a passage in `Pro JPA 2 Mastering the java Persistence API`?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am new to `JPA`, I am reading `Pro JPA 2 Mastering the java Persistence API` and I have read the following passage:

> a flush of the persistence context could occur at any time if the
>   persistence provider deems it necessary.

**My questions**

- What is `deems it necessary`?
- In which cases the providers `deems it necessary`?

I want to understand the meaning in detail of this sentence `deems it necessary`. Any help is welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: This means, the behaviour is implementation dependent. The provider may flush (but is not obliged to) whenever it "deems it necessary".

Comment: @Henry knowing that in our entreprise we use `EclipseLink` is it possible to provide a detailed explanation of cases when EclpiseLink uses `flush`

Comment: Probably yes, if you inspect the source code of EclipseLink. But keep in mind, that this may change in future versions. So your application must not rely on any specific behaviour.

Comment: @Henry Knowing that flush affects the result , is it a best practice to use flush manually (explicitly in code by developer) or leave it to the provider?

Comment: Overusing `flush` can have negative effect on the performance. So it is best in general to leave it to the provider. There are some rare exceptions when you need to flush manually.

Comment: @Henry thank you for your help =)

Answer (score 1):

One such scenario is as per [JPA 2.1 Specification - Section 3.10.8 Queries and Flush Mode](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1521976042_680e87a5e95417aaa8c9da5fa589018b) - `The persistence provider is responsible for ensuring that all updates to the state of all entities in the persistence context which could potentially affect the result of the query are visible to the processing of the query.`

Although it is implementation dependent, but you can notice below behavior with hibernate as persistence provider deciding to flush before firing an HQL as the state in the persistence context could affect the query result.

So with Hibernate as persistence provider,

1. Open an entityManager.
2. Create new `Employee` entity and call `persist` method on it.
3. It may not result in an immediate `insert` statement because session acts as a transactional-write behind cache and tries to defer flushing up until last moment possible.
4. Fire a JPQL to get the `count of employees using the entityManager`.
5. At this point, you would see an insert statement is fired to persist the newly created employee before firing the `select count(*) from employee JPQL`.

So in this case it has decided to flush the state because the insertion of employee object could affect the result of JPQL query.

Comment: As I understand we can't really know the behaviour of the provider (hibernate) when it comes to `flush`. Knowing that flush affects the result , is it a best practice to use `flush` manually (explicitly in code by developer) or leave it to the provider?

Comment: I would say leave it to the provider and it would take more informed decision as to when to flush unless you come across usecase that demands a manual flush which I believe should be very rare. I personally have never felt the need for manual flush.